# In google test can a test be marked as skipped instead of failed, during test execution

Tags: automated-tests, googletest

In google test is there a way of marking a test as SKIPPED if an assertion fails?

e.g. `ASSERT_TRUE(1 != 1)`

So if the above statement fails, can I add something to gtest to mark the test as skipped instead of failed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not that I know of.  Probably for good reason, since it looks kinda cheaty to "skip" a test only once you hit a failure!  If you know a test will fail before running it, then you can [disable it temporarily](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#temporarily-disabling-tests) by prepending `DISABLED_` to the test name.

This seems like a better option since the test code still gets compiled, but the suite's overall result is unaffected since the test is not run.  The output nags you by reminding you how many disabled tests you have, and you can always force the disabled test to run if required using the `--gtest_also_run_disabled_tests` arg.

By the way, gtest provides [ways to explicitly cause your test to fail](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/assertions.md#explicit-success-and-failure-success-failure) rather than doing `ASSERT_TRUE(1 != 1)`.

Comment: that 1 != 1 gives me cancer, why not just use false

Comment: Because that was the example in the OP.

Comment: "kinda cheaty" In the words of Lemony Snicket: A phrase which hear means a terrible coding practice that will lead to pain and misery for someone, maybe you, later.

Comment: the link is broken but I believe you simply call FAIL(), you can also pipe a message to it like so: FAIL() << "this test failed for xyz";

Comment: I think DISABLED should be used in cases where running the test would be bad (like it fails but you haven't prioritized fixing it yet, or when it takes too long to run on every build, but might be run prior to release). `GTEST_SKIP()` should be used if some transient condition would make the test fail or otherwise be undesirable to run.

Answer (score 2):

`GTEST_SKIP` can be used to mark a test during execution.

For example:

```
TEST(SkipTest, DoesSkip) {
  GTEST_SKIP() << "Skipping single test";
  EXPECT_EQ(0, 1);  // Won't fail; it won't be executed
}
```

Comment: I should point out that skipping a test is a reasonable approach if some environmental preconditions are not met. For example, I have CUDA code that can be compiled anywhere, but can only be run if there is a GPU present. My test framework calls `GTEST_SKPI()` if there is no GPU.